# What's the use case for a 0.1µF electrolytic cap?

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor

I've noticed [100nF electrolytic capacitors](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/445/865230640001-1726722.pdf) are made and sold, which means people are probably buying them, but... ESR is huge, ripple current is tiny, accuracy is low, and they're larger and more expensive than the alternatives.

So... what is the actual use case? Has anyone seen them used in an actual product?

Comment: Not to mention that the lifetime of electrolytic caps is much worse than ceramic or film too.  Unlike ceramics they are stable with DC bias, but I don't see a lot of use cases for a 0.1 uF electrolytic.  Better volumetric capacitance density for large values, but not for 0.1 uF.  Maybe someone knows something that we don't?  Maybe the lack of audible noise due to the piezoelectric effect that you get with ceramics?

Comment: In rare case you need an overdamped  lossy , leaky circuit, it’s a good choice and is not microphonic,

Comment: So hobbyists can have a 0.1uf electrolytic in their kit

Comment: My guess is a combination of low cost and stable capacitance with DC bias.  Otherwise you'd probably just use an MLCC and possibly a resistor.

Comment: Some people may buy it thinking it’s a good part. But in the fine print “ This electronic component has been designed and developed for usage in general electronic equipment only. This product is not authorized for use in equipment where a higher safety standard and reliability standard is especially required or where a failure of the product is reasonably expected to cause severe personal injury or death, nor intended for use in areas such as military, aerospace, aviation, nuclear control, submarine, automotive control, train control, ship control), transportation,disaster prevention, medical

Comment: I would've thought that DC bias characteristics could be a reason to use an electrolytic cap, but at 100nF, even X7R ceramics are still quite stable with DC bias. Another thing that comes to mind is failure mode - electrolytics don't usually short, ceramics almost always do when they fail.

Comment: The plot thickens... 100nF film cap costs 2 cents, could it be that the answer is, as usual, "it's half a cent cheaper"?

Comment: @bobflux if you are buying 10,000,000 then it is significant.

Comment: Not interestingly, electrolytics are ~50% cheaper than MLCCs @ 200V from RS Components.

Comment: Possibly as a last-ditch substitute part if you need to change values and you already made the board or if whoever did the layout had a brain fart and put in the wrong footprint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- low sensitivity to DC bias
- (that kind of results from the above) less non-linear behaviour (e.g. in signal, especially audio, applications)
- cheaper to make for high voltage ratings
- less to no microphonic effect
- maybe desirable thermal properties compensating some other component's thermal properties in a special application?
- space goblins

Comment: Less to none? 1234

Comment: Damn, I was hoping for an answer like "oh I use these all the time and that's the reason" but since the question was closed for bogus reason, here's your +25 ;)

Comment: I don't understand why it was closed, it does not solicit for opinions but hard facts where a 100nF electrolytic is better than ceramic. +1 for space goblins.

Comment: @bobflux I don't even get these 25 pts; I made this a community wiki because I thought this was not something I was knowledgeable enough, and so felt a lot of the commenters, still collecting the comments seemed worthwhile.

Comment: @Justme I voted to reopen. Can't really see the question-for-opinion in there.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yeah, I was hoping for an example of a product that uses these, which is definitely not opinion based...